# Angular-RxJS- Hide spinner in the middle of long API call and continue API call

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

> The response time of the API call varies between 2 and 30 seconds.
> After initializing the API call, if the API call will take more than
> five seconds, at the time of the 6th second, I have to perform some
> action (hide spinner), and the call has to continue until it is
> complete.

What can be the best combination of RxJS operators to accomplish that?

Comment: I'd take a look at `takeUntil` and `timer`.

Comment: [Merge with timer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge), see first example.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rx delay should be able to trigger an action after certain time delay

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

doSomething(): Observable<boolean> {
 //place your logic here 
   return of(true);
} //you can specify what type of observable to use number, string etc..

const $delayed 
  = doSomething
   .pipe(delay(6000))
   .subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Where do we get control here at 6th second to hide spinner?? And API Call has to execute as it is without any delays or interruptions..

Comment: 1- You set a css classes to control the visibility of your spinner then you set the hiding css class to your spinner element in the js code of doSomething function

Comment: The above will not work, why because Initial 6 seconds delay and then calling the API is not what I am looking for. The API service and timer should start parellally, I should get the timer callback control and the API should continue until it is done. Provide an example, or working solution if possible.

Comment: No one instructed to call an api after 6 seconds ! the code simply projects how to delay a function calling after 6 seconds,  the way you combine this with your logic is totally up to you , in matter of fact in your case you should call this method immediately after you issue your api call or use Rx merge or join to issue two calls simultaneously